# Will the 19.10 to 20.04 upgrade path convert the file system to zfs?

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, zfs

I've read that one new feature of 20.04 is ZFS:

https://www.zdnet.com/article/ubuntu-20-04-arrives-with-linux-5-4-kernel-and-wireguard-vpn/

Will the upgrade path also turn existing ext4 file systems into ZFS?  That sounds slow and potentially dangerous: Is that even possible?

Comment: Typically the system updates to NOT alter existing disk layouts - because of the dangers you stated.  Also, 20.04 can install *fine* on standard ext4 even with 20.04.  (So, why would it force you to ZFS?)

Comment: The new feature is ZFS *support* (as the linked article clearly states). Nobody is getting force-migrated to ZFS. New installs have the option of using ZFS.

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes. A “no” would be fine. 

Comment: @Mittenchops The StackExchange network receives poorly questions that show a clear lack of research, hence the downvotes. A question that can simply be answered by a blunt "no" is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Thanks, @undu. A blunt "no" as an answer is definitely a poor fit for this site.  A considerate answer backed up by a reference to a primary source is a much better answer.  Please see the following Stackoverflow reference on how to ask a good question, which is often helpful for newcomers to Stack Exchange sites: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Mittenchops Well, you are the one saying "A “no” would be fine." after all... Had you read the link you provided to me, you would understand that your question is not good. Like I said, "hence the downvotes". Feel free to answer, I won't take this conversation any further.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The feature is **ZFS Support** not forcing everyone onto it.  Root-on-ZFS is an **optional** choice in the 20.04 Installation ISO but is not enforced nor doing anything on upgrade.